# Simply changing avi file to mpg accelerates the video while audio maintains the original pace

Tags: video-encoding, mencoder

I have a avi file with streams as follows

```
Stream 0: Video, MPEG2 video, 480x576, 25fps
Stream 1: Audio, MP2, 44100Hz, 192kbps
```

I am trying to convert the above file into SVCD complaint mpg file. So, I used the following command to convert it.

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -of mpeg -mpegopts format=xsvcd -o o.mpg I.avi
```

The output video now has the following specs

```
Stream 0: Audio, MP2, 44100Hz, 192kbps
Stream 1: Video, MPEG2 video, 480x576, 50fps
```

The output video runs the audio at normal pace but the video is played at accelerated pace. The original video ends in 35mins 27s but the output video ends in 25mins 43s.

What am I doing wrong?

Also I do not understand how did the fps change, after all I simply copied the video to the new container.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the frame rate has doubled in the output there, but add **-fps 25 -ofps 25 -speed 1** to explictly define the frame rate and speed of the output video.

Comment: Actually I had tried that and it did not work.